# How to sum value goup by 4 Quarter data into one value in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set that contains quarterly data value. But now I want to sum the quarterly values which have the same year.

Data h :

```
time     value
01JAN90   23
01APR90   31
01JUL90   13
01OCT90   45
01JAN91   11
01APR91    4
01JUL91    1
01OCT91    17
```

I want my result data like this：

```
time     value
1990       53
1991       35
```

Comment: `time` is a character variable, or is a numeric date variable?

Comment: Can you clarify what "sum the quarterly values which have the same year" means?  That sounds like summing all values by year, which does not quite produce the result data you are showing. Please confirm. In the meantime I have my answer as year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `time` variable is numeric, you can use a `FORMAT` statement within `PROC SUMMARY` to automatically extract the year as the `PROC` runs. (Thanks to @Joe for showing this in comments to my original answer.)

```
PROC SUMMARY NWAY DATA = h;
    CLASS time;

    FORMAT time YEAR. ;

    OUTPUT 
        OUT = result (
            KEEP = year value
        )
        SUM (value) =
    ;
RUN;
```

Comment: If it's truly a date variable, this is not needed (hence my original question).  You can use a format to get SUMMARY to directly summarize by year.  If it's character, this is probably the best simple way (using substr or similar to get to the year), though you *could* make a format that got around that also (just with more work than makes sense).

Comment: I never knew that - I just tested by adding a `FORMAT time YEAR.` statement to my `PROC SUMMARY` and it worked! Thanks for this. OK if I incorporate your change into my answer?

Comment: Since your date value is likely character based on other questions you've asked, change year = year(input(time, anydtdte.)); to get the appropriate year value.

Comment: Permission to incorporate is implicit in comments here, so, sure.